# should I leave my company or stay so my manager can assign me work

Tags: job-offer, software-development

I joined a telecommunication company 7 months ago as software engineer, I have more than 12 years of software development experience. The product is new with no client yet.
Initially I worked with Software Architect but he left company after 4 months of my joining.
I found that most code is written by another guy who left before I joined.
After I joined, 4 months later same guy came back in project. I tried to work along with him, he seems good guy but he tried to delay the demo which we both have to give in company. i.e. showing what we build.

Later on another guy joins the company and due to the nature of remote work. They both started working together, there was no requirements in project. It was based on an idea which few people knew and for MVP or initial demo, we as a team have to show something.
I realized that both are working as I can see code checked in in source control but they didn't discussed or invited me in any meetings.

I asked the guy (who has worked on project before) few times that is there any work I can help but he said he would tell me but didn't. After few days, they presented a demo and took credits and I definitely was out of the team.

I tried to work alone on side work items but they both always tries to resist my changes in code. Now after 2 months I am removed from team citing funding cuts. me and scrum master are removed.

My manager who is not part of team but he overseas multiple projects said that he would adjust me to another team, he introduced me to another team but their skill demands are not exactly matching with mine.

Now 15 days passed, and I got another offer outside company and I haven't heard back from my manager.

Should I leave my current company or wait for manager to come back with another project? Does my manager wants me to leave as I am excluded from the team?

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those impossible-to-answer questions, because we're all random strangers on the internet and only you know the full extent of your current situation. Additionally, only you know the consequences of leaving, or otherwise.

If you don't like either the manager or the company, then leave; you have an open offer.

If you do like the company and your manager, do the project you've been assigned, and do it well. Then ask for another, more to your liking. It may not be 100% your skills, but it sounds like they're happy to pay you to grow your professional acumen.

Don't base your decision on a transient like the project (unless its a really long term one, or an obvious disaster in the making). We all have projects we don't like from time to time. You have to decide for yourself if it's worth uprooting and starting again.